# What is the equivalent of ps command in perl?

Tags: windows, perl, ps

I am using `ps -C <executable name>` on Linux, but the same does not work on Windows.

How can I perform the same check in Perl so that it is platform independent?

Comment: I'm going to suggest migration to Server Fault. Granted you're dealing with perl, but I think the target audience there has a higher likelihood of answering the question.

Comment: According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ps_(Unix), "The `ps` command is analogous to the Microsoft Windows `tasklist` command. In Windows PowerShell, `ps` is a predefined command alias for the `Get-Process` cmdlet which basically serves the same purpose."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to use [Win32::Process::List](http://search.cpan.org/~rpagitsch/Win32-Process-List/)

```
use 5.12.0;
use warnings;
use Win32::Process::List;

my $P = Win32::Process::List->new();
if($P->IsError == 1) {
    die $P->GetErrorText;
}

my %list = $P->GetProcesses();
foreach my $key (keys %list) {
    # $list{$key} = process name, $key=PID
    say sprintf("%25s %10s", $list{$key}, $key);
}
```

And process appropriately.

Comment: I need something that will work for both linux and Windows.. Is there anything simpler that can be used?

Comment: Unfortunately you'll be hard pressed to find that. Since the solution is platform dependent the underlying C that perl is linking to is as well.

Comment: You'll have to take something like this, and the unix version, and wrap them up in a module which figures out which one to use.  Hide the dirty.